# Unmanaged Raster Catalog Relative Paths?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster-catalog, file-path

Is it possible to store relative paths in an unmanaged raster catalog?

What I want to do:

```
C:\Folder\File.gdb
    UnmanagedRasterCatalog1
        ..\..\Data\MyRaster\Raster.File

C:\Data
    MyRaster
        Raster.File
```

I see this feature request which leads me to believe it's not possible:

- Relative paths in unmanaged raster catalogs - http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000brlG

When I use the Repair Raster Catalog Paths tool it accepts a relative path as the new path parameter but when I export the paths using the Export Raster Catalog Paths tool the paths are the full path. So it looks like it is resolving the full path and putting that in instead of the relative path.

**Repair Raster Catalog Paths tool**

[image]

**Export Raster Catalog Paths output**

[image]

Comment: Did you actually try it?

Comment: Yea I gave it a try using the [Repair Raster Catalog Paths](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000092000000) toolbox tool . This link is for the ArcPy function... I just used the toolbox tool though which just calls this...

Comment: from Esri forum thread [Relative Paths in Unmanaged Raster Catalog?](https://geonet.esri.com/message/545846#545846)  it seems [tag:personal-gdb] is allowed relative paths, though that may also have performance issues. Also please consider voting for [ArcGIS Idea - Relative path names for mosaic datasets](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087E00000005ArqIAE)

Answer (score 1):

A workaround may be to use UNC path, by sharing the folder on the network:
\MachineName\SharedFolder...

Comment: Unfortunately UNC paths are a no go because of the performance degradation. The raster catalogs are being used for ArcGIS server services which need to be performant.